# how to set top layout guide and bottom layout guide for uitableviewcontroller in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift

I have gone through every solution which I found in stack overflow, but none of them worked out for me.

I am having a transparent navigation bar above my `UITableViewController` and all my data is overlapping with status bar and navigation while I am scrolling the table view up.

*note:* I want that transparent effect on my navigation bar. please, I don't want view controller solution, I have static table views too and we cannot use static type tableview in `UIViewController`.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the navigation bar to cover any of the data at all?  When you say transparent is that what you mean?

Comment: actually i have a app background which is dark and app looks odd when i try to put any color on navigation bar so i made that transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem when using a `UITableViewController` but not on swift3.0, so not sure if it help.

By default, `UITableViewController` has `Adjust Scroll View Insets` as enable. Unchecking it solves the issue for me.

[image]

With the `insets` enable, it does not start below the `UINavigationBar`. Therefore disabling the `insets` solve the problem for me.

Comment: sorry man didnt work out doing so....... I also have tried with this in view will appear:

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0);

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of a similar issue, only my nav bar wasn't transparent, so data was just disappearing down there.  I found that my constraints didn't take into account the height of the nav bar.  Try making the scrollbar bottom constraint equal to `view.bottom + 50` for arguments sake, then adjust that value until you're happy with where it sits.

I found that 30px works for me.
[image: ScrollView Constraint]